# How to communicate with an external db?

Tags: node.js, api, heroku

I created a simple API with Nodejs that communicate with an external database.
Everything works in localhost.

But it works because the IP of my computer is authorized in the white list IP of my databse.

But I deployed my app with Heroku, it also works correctly but I can't communicate with my DB because I can't authorize any IP from Heroku to connect to my DB.

So how can I authorize the requests from my Heroku app to access the data of the external DB ?

Comment: You can't. Your Heroku app could be on any of a wide range of IPs, per e.g. https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-add-heroku-dynos-to-our-allowlist-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku. If you can't allow them all on your database, you'd need some kind of proxy with an IP you _can_ allow.